# Not able to select element in footer using selinium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to select and click on an element which is located in footer.

Below is the code

[image]

I tried getting right `XPath` using Chrome console. Below are the code that I have tried. It is not highlighting the element. Please suggest if why it is not locating.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("li#btnEnableEditing.LoginOkButtonFooter")).click();
```

And I have also tried using move to as below

```
a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("li#btnEnableEditing.LoginOkButtonFooter"))).click().perform();

a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='btnEnableEditing']"))).click().perform();
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's happening for all 3 things that you tried? e.g. is it giving an error / nothing happens? If you can't comment please update your question as a response.

Comment: If everything fails you can try JavascriptExecutor.

Comment: No Error messages and no response. Element is not getting highlighted.. Manually, first the button highlights when I move the mouse on it and then I will click.

Answer (score 1):

The `xpath` you are using is invalid. The first two code lines are actually used in `cssSelector`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li#btnEnableEditing.LoginOkButtonFooter")).click();
```

Or just

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#btnEnableEditing")).click();
```

Or using `By.id`

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btnEnableEditing")).click();
```

And you are missing square brackets in the last one

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnEnableEditing']")).click();
```

Comment: Guy, can you explain me, If `id` attribute is present then why are you using `css selector` here.

Comment: @JainishKapadia I based my answer on the OP code. You can use `By.id` of course.